# Как сделать шестиугольник в xml?

Tags: java, android, ui

Такой вопрос, как сделать шестиугольник в xml? Например с помощью shape. И можно ли это сделать?

Желаемый результат должен выглядеть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ребята, там под текстом действительно что-то есть. Очень похоже на шестиугольник!

Comment: @vp_arth Он просто с закругленными углами

Comment: @vp_arth и с плюсиком всредине

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Перевод](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296863/how-to-create-hexagon-shape-in-xml-format)

Лучшим решением будет использовать `VectorDrawable`

Шестиугольник:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="628.0"
android:viewportWidth="726.0" android:width="27dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#00ffffff"
    android:pathData="m723,314c-60,103.9 -120,207.8 -180,311.8 -120,0 -240,0 -360,0C123,521.8 63,417.9 3,314 63,210.1 123,106.2 183,2.2c120,0 240,0 360,0C603,106.2 663,210.1 723,314Z"
    android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="4"/>
</vector>
```

Для поддержки API ранее Lollipop нужно использовать `VectorDrawableCompat` вместо `VectorDrawable`

Comment: О, спасибо большое!

Comment: @vp_arth у вас там в мире php все по-другому)))